# Why is one expression constant, but not the other?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, static-assert

Why does Visual Studio 2013 compiler reject the first static assert (Error C2057), but not the second?

```
#include <limits>

typedef int Frequency;

const Frequency minHz{ 0 };
const Frequency maxHz{ std::numeric_limits<Frequency>::max() };
const Frequency invalidHz{ -1 };
static_assert(minHz < maxHz, "minHz must be less than maxHz");                // C2057
static_assert(invalidHz < minHz || invalidHz > maxHz, "invalidHz is valid");  // OK
```

Comment: Probably because the [VS 2013 compiler doesn't support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) `constexpr` yet.

Comment: @DarkFalcon: The VS 2013 compiler never will! :)

Comment: Compiles well on VS2015 RC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd guess that, in that implementation, `max()` isn't `constexpr` (as C++11 says it should be), so that `maxHz` isn't a constant expression, while `minHz` and `invalidHz` are.

Thus the first assert fails because it can't be evaluated at compile time; the second succeeds, because the comparison before `||` is true, so the second comparison isn't evaluated.

Comment: This appears correct - if the order is switched (in the second assert) it fails to compile like the first.

Comment: Is this just an MSVC thing or a common problem with this type of initialization?

Comment: @WillBickford: The lack of `constexpr` is an MSVC thing - it should be a constant expression on any conforming C++11 (or later) implementation. The requirement for a constant expression in `static_assert`, and the short-circuit evaluation of `||`, are standard.

Comment: I meant the effect of initializing a const variable with a non-constexpr. Shouldn't that generate a compiler warning or error?

Comment: @WillBickford: No, it just means that the variable, while still constant (i.e. unable to be changed) has to be initialised at run-time and can't be used as a constant expression.

Comment: On VC2015, it is implemented as `static constexpr _Ty (max)() _THROW0()` - hence the `static_assert` works.